# finding the complete path of an image

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\siva\Downloads\ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition-master\asl_dataset\1
```

like the above path there will be several images 0-9 and a-z hence there are 36 classes. In the above path the last one indicates the number 1. In the below program i have to find that one by traversing it  but it ended up with

> ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition-master producing a key error  at  y_train.append(classes[fullpath[n + 1:t]])
>   because classes[ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition-master] does not exists.
>       def load_data_set():
>       for path in paths:
>           for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
>               for filename in filenames:
>                   if filename.endswith(".jpeg"):
>                       fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
>                       img = load_img(fullpath)
>                       img = img_to_array(img)
>                       print fullpath
>                       x_train.append(img)
>                       t = fullpath.rindex("/")
>                       fullpath = fullpath[0:t]
>                       n = fullpath.rindex("/")
>                       #print fullpath[n + 1:t]
>                       y_train.append(classes[fullpath[n + 1:t]])

Comment: This is illegible

Comment: Please format..

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you exactly want but if you want to loop over the image files in that directory and print their path, you can simply do something like this:

```
import os

image_directory = "C:\Users\siva\Downloads\ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition-master\asl_dataset\"
image_list = os.listdir(image_directory)

# Loop over images in directory
for image_name in image_list:
    image_path = os.path.join(image_directory, image_name)
    print image_path
```